# Directory names - Stripping white space and other formatting

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, sed

I am new to bash and learning the power tools of `sed` , `awk` and many more this platform provides. In my linux box I have a music directory that contains subdirectories. These subdirectories have uppercasing in the name. I am trying to make all of the folders inside that music directory lower case and strip out spacing. In exception of not changing anything that comes after the last hyphen other than striping a whitespace in the subdirectory name. A file may have many hyphens. I am just taking into account the last one. How could I do so?

```
while read -r file; do
    new_file=$(echo "$file" | sed -re 's/^([^-]*)-\s*([^\.]*)/\L\1\E-\2/' -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/_-/-/g')
        if [ "$file" != "$new_file" ]; then
                mv "$file" "$new_file"
        fi
done
```

For example:

***Input***

```
New- Survivor - Eye Of The Tiger – 12wOlL
```

***Desired Result:***

```
new-survivor_-_ eye_of_the_tiger-12wOlL
```

***Current Result:***

```
new-Survivor_-_ Eye_of_The_Tiger-12wOlL
```

Comment: You need to clarify the rules of conversion a bit more. Why `New- Survivor` became `new-survivor` but `Survivor - Eye` became `survivor_-_ eye` and again `Tiger – 12wOlL` became `tiger-12wOlL`. When should space after `-` be converted to `_` and when should it be stripped?

Comment: @anubhava I am appending `New- ` everything else is the original file name. That is why the other hyphens get surrounded with underscore. The exception is the first and the last hyphen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
s='New- Survivor - Eye Of The Tiger - 12wOlL'
echo "$s" | sed 's/^\(.*\)\(-[^-]*\)$/\L\1\E\2/; s/ *- */-/; s/^\(.*\) \+- *\([^-]*\)$/\1-\2/; s/ /_/g'
new-survivor_-_eye_of_the_tiger-12wOlL
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your sed command like below,

```
$ echo 'New- Survivor - Eye Of The Tiger – 12wOlL' | sed -re 's/^([^-]*-)\s*([^–]*)\s*–/\L\1\L\2–/;s/ /_/g;s/_-_/_-_ /g;s/_–_/-/g'
new-survivor_-_ eye_of_the_tiger-12wOlL
```